# Join results of 3 queries

Tags: sql, join

i have 3 worked queries, but i don't know how to combin them in one query.
TABLES :

```
------------------        --------------------------       -----------------
PIECE                     MCARTEFIDENT                     MCARTEFIDLIG
------------------        --------------------------       -----------------
ET_LIBELLE : Store        MFC_ETABLISSEMENT : STORE        MFL_ETABLISSEMENT
GP_NUMERO : TICKET        MFC_VALDISPOTHEO                 MFL_NBPASSAGEAPRES
-------------------       --------------------------
--QUERY 1
select [et_libelle] AS [STORE NAME],COUNT([GP_NUMERO])
FROM PIECE
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET1 ON gp_etablissement=ET1.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
GROUP BY et_libelle

--QUERY 2
SELECT MFC_ETABLISSEMENT as [STORE NAME], COUNT (MFC_VALDISPOTHEO)
FROM MCARTEFIDENT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON MFC_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
GROUP BY MFC_ETABLISSEMENT

--QUERY 3
SELECT MFL_ETABLISSEMENT AS [STORE NAME], MFL_NBPASSAGEAPRES
FROM MCARTEFIDLIG
LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET3 ON MFL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET3.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
GROUP BY MFL_ETABLISSEMENT
```

columns should be the result after combine :

```
[et_libelle] (Query 1),
COUNT([GP_NUMERO]) (Query 1),
COUNT([GP_NUMERO]) (Query 2),
MFL_NBPASSAGEAPRES (Query 3)
```

Comment: you can use union to join 3 queries

Comment: which column should be the result   after combine??

Comment: Qualify the column names so the queries make sense.  Someone reading the question has no idea which columns come from which tables.  Is `et_libelle` really the same as `MFC_ETABLISSEMENT` and `MFL_ETABLISSEMENT`?  Why the `left join`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use your 3 queries  as subqiery and join

```
select a.[STORE NAME], a.count_gp_numero, b.count_mfc_valdispotheo, c.MFL_NBPASSAGEAPRES
from  (
  select [et_libelle] AS [STORE NAME], COUNT([GP_NUMERO]) count_gp_numero
  FROM PIECE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET1 ON gp_etablissement=ET1.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
  GROUP BY et_libelle
 )  a
 left  join  (
    SELECT MFC_ETABLISSEMENT as [STORE NAME], COUNT(MFC_VALDISPOTHEO) b.count_mfc_valdispotheo
    FROM MCARTEFIDENT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON MFC_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
    GROUP BY MFC_ETABLISSEMENT
 ) b on a.[STORE NAME] = b.[STORE NAME]
 left join  (
    SELECT MFL_ETABLISSEMENT AS [STORE NAME], MFL_NBPASSAGEAPRES
    FROM MCARTEFIDLIG
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET3 ON MFL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET3.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
    GROUP BY MFL_ETABLISSEMENT
 ) c on a.[STORE NAME] = c.[STORE NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to speculate, my guess would be that you want:

```
select e.*,
       (select count(*)
        from piece p
        where p.gp_etablissement = e.et_etablissement
       ),
       (select count(*)
        from MCARTEFIDENT mfc
        where mfc.MFC_ETABLISSEMENT = e.et_etablissement
       ),
       (select MFL_NBPASSAGEAPRES  -- perhaps a `sum()` here???
        from MCARTEFIDENT mfl
        where mfl.MFL_ETABLISSEMENT = e.et_etablissement
       )       
from etabliss e;
```